# Ignore insert when older last_updated record

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table in Maria DB with several columns.

It is very possible that a record with the same key but slightly older data already exists. And I always need to have in the database the more updated record.

Therefore, to insert data I use

`insert into ... on duplicate key update`

and then:

```
name = values(name), heart_rate= values(heart_rate), last_updated = values(last_updated) etc
```

The problem is that due to network congestion, the older value may come later than the more updated value. Each record that is inserted also has a last_updated field, which is a date.

If the last_updated of the newly received record is executed in an

```
insert into ... on duplicate key update
```

I want it to be ignored. Is this possible? Is there a way for my database to only have the records with the most recent last_updated field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` must already have a `WHERE` clause. You didn't show us that, so this is a guess.

You can incorporate a `WHERE` condition based on your `last_updated` column and the value you pass from your application. It will look something like this.

```
 WHERE <<incoming_id>> = id
   AND <<incoming_last_updated>> > last_updated
```

If your incoming `last_updated` value is earlier or the same than the one already in your table, this `WHERE` clause matches no rows, so your `...UPDATE...` does nothing.